# My color/material nodes aren't applying to the entire object

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, color

Here is a screenshot of what is happening. You can see that the sides of the fireball are grey rather than red, and the sides of the skull are the same way. When you render preview it, they are both the color they are assigned, and also white. When you move around to view the objects from different sides, the white/grey sheen will move around as well and different parts of that object become colored. Anyone know what is going on?[image]

Comment: I don't have the same effect with the same node setup, could you please share at least one of your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: double check if you have only one material, If the sides are filled in and if it looks the same in rendered mode